# What merchants sell praxis kits?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

In my apartment building one of my neighbors is selling praxis kits for 10k

> He only has two

**Are there any other merchants like that across the game, or I was hoarding all that money for no good reason?**

Comment: I naturally hoard money and hardly ever buy things in these kinds of games, but I'd like to know this too.

Comment: If it's like Human Revolution there will be 2 or maybe 3 merchants who sell Praxis kits, for a total of 4-5 in the entire game.  However, there are even more than that number lying around in the world to be found or receivable as rewards for side quests.  That being said, I too usually end up with about 50K extra credits at the end of the game. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Base Game

The total number of merchants selling Praxis kits in the base game (i.e. before any DLC) is

> one (Tars)

and the total number of kits sold is

> four

with

> two available before Utulek (*aka* Prague 1), one available between Utulek and GARM (*aka* Prague 2), and one available after you visit TF29 after GARM (*aka* Prague 3)

## DLC

1. *Desperate Measures*: This pre-order standalone add-on has no merchants of any kind (let alone Praxis sellers).  There are no credit chips or sellable-only pickups to be found.  (The designers of the hacking puzzles, however, forgot to remove some of the bank account rewards.)
2. *System Rift*: This add-on has no merchants of any kind.

Answer (score -4):

They go for 10,000 credits. A merchant on the second floor of Jensen's building will sell 2